# Composer unable to update with zfc-user-doctrine-orm

Tags: zend-framework, composer-php

I am trying to use composer to upload doctrine2 ORM to my project but I keep getting the error message below. I would be grateful for any help resolving it.

**the composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "0.1.*",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.2.*"
    }
}
```

**the error message:**

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master.
    - zf-commons/zfc-user 0.1.2 requires zf-commons/zfc-base 0.* -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base v0.1.2, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.1, zf-commons/zfc-base v0.1.2.
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base v0.1.2.
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1.
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0.
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master, zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.1.
    - Can only install one of: zf-commons/zfc-base v0.1.2, zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master.
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-user 0.1.2 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user 0.1.2.
```

**My attempted solution:**

```
"zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.1.2"

"zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1.2",
```

I tried both solutions but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
{
"name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
"description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
],
"homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-base": "0.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "0.1.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "0.1.*",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.2.*"
}
}
```